# How to show custom Django form validation errors as standard pop-ups

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have the following custom form validation:

**forms.py**

```
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_allegato(allegato):
    ext = os.path.splitext(allegato.name)[1]
    valid_extensions = [ '.pdf']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extension.')

class MyForm(forms.Form):
  allegato = forms.FileField(required=False, validators=[validate_allegato])
```

In the template, I would like to show the `ValidationError` as the standard HTML popups (as "Please fill in this field").

Is it possible?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think it's easier to check in frontend for this purpose. If you want to raise validation error in front, you maybe use javascript.

Comment: @seuling: thank you for your hint but I'm wondering if I can fix the issue by only using python/html

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
render your error message to your template, instead of raise error.

Solution 2:
You can overwrite Form.clean() method under your form class, and all of validation should be done inside this method. You can use Form.add_error() method to have your error message display. Document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/